# R: filtering in loop

Tags: r, loops, filter, character

I am to perform lm() on different dataset via loop, which should first make dataset using filter() and then to perform lm() on filtered dataset and save the results.
However, I always get this error and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

> "Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"

My code:

```
a<-c("var1", "var2", "var3") #character vector


for (b in a){
  dataset <- dataset%>%filter(variable_name == b)
  lm<- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=dataset)
assign(paste(b, "lm", sep='_'), lm)
}
```

Can anyone help me please? I know it is really elementary. Based on searching results, I've also tried it with

```
dataset <- dataset%>%filter(variable_name == **paste0("'",b,"'")**)
```

but always get the same error...Thanks!

Comment: You are updating the `dataset` in global env in each iteration which would fail when you go into next iteration instead create temporary dataset (after the first iteration, the dataset have only rows where variable_name values are 'var1' .e. `tmp <- dataset%>%filter(variable_name == b)` and use that in `lm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the original object in the global environment with the subset of rows will throw error for the subsequent iterations as `==` returns 0 rows for 'var2' and 'var3' (when the `dataset` have only 'var1' value in 'variable_name').  Instead, create a temporary object (which could be removed as well) within the loop

```
for (b in a){
  tmp <- subset(dataset, variable_name == b)
   model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = tmp)
   assign(paste(b, "lm", sep='_'), model)
   rm(tmp)
 }
```

---

It may be also better to create a single `list` object instead of multiple objects in the global env.  `split` would be faster than `==` which splits the data into subset of data in a `list` based on the values in 'variable_name'

```
model_lst <- lapply(split(dataset, dataset$variable_name), function(tmp)
          lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = tmp))
```

Or if we prefer to use the 'a' vector (assuming there are more `unique` values in 'variable_name' and want only the models based on 'a' vector)

```
model_lst <- lapply(a, function(b) {
            lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = subset(dataset, variable_name == b)
  })
```

Comment: ah okay, i understand what i was doing wrong now!. thank you very much!!